# Frequency Domain of a Periodic Fourier Transform Signal

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I've been working on a project to send data via sound waves.
The way I've carried this out is by encoding the data in pulses in the frequency domain, and then creating a unique sound wave containing that information.  I've used python to plot that, which has given me:

```
import scipy as sp
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


paynowString = "00020101021126380009SG.PAYNOW010100211+658128992803010520400005303702545800.005802SG59006009Singapore620401006304"

characters = []

def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

characters = split(paynowString)
print(characters)

ascii_characters = [ord(char) for char in characters]
print(ascii_characters)

positive_x_domain = np.zeros(9*len(ascii_characters))

rhs = []
xr = list(positive_x_domain)
for i in range(len(ascii_characters)):
    rhs = rhs + xr[i*9:(i*9+9)]+[ascii_characters[i]]
positive_x_domain = rhs + xr[(i+9)*9:]
positive_x_domain = np.asarray(positive_x_domain)
print(positive_x_domain)

negative_x_domain = np.flip(positive_x_domain)
print(negative_x_domain)

origin = np.array([0])

x_domain = np.concatenate((negative_x_domain, origin), axis = None)
x_domain = np.concatenate((x_domain, positive_x_domain), axis = None)
print(x_domain)


plt.plot(np.arange((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), ((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), x_domain)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

After which, this gives me a graph that represents the frequency domain:
[image: Frequency Domain]

Following this, I then apply the Fourier Transform on the frequency graph to get:

```
sound_wave = fft.ifft(x_domain)

plt.plot((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), (((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), sound_wave)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.axis([-0.1, 2500, -0.1, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
#end of sending the sound wave
```

This gives me another graph that represents the sound wave:
[image: Sound Wave]

However, I was trying to get a periodic sound wave, which I was not able to get from this graph. From my understanding, if the positive and negative frequencies are reflected across the y-axis, i.e. the magnitudes of the pulses in the positive and negative x-axis of the frequency domain are the same, then the sound wave produced after the Fourier Transform will be periodic.

Is there something wrong with my understanding, or does my code have some issues?
If so, how can I ensure that the sound wave that is produced by my Inverse Fourier Transform will be periodic, as well as playable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know that, FFT(Fast fourier transform) and FT(Fourier Transform) has some different things in algorithm. That's mean is, FFT does not extend the algorithm as much as FT does. You can see details in the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Maybe I should explain part by part.
Your sound(Analog data) getting from microphone(Convert to digital data).
Then, you want to get FFT and IFT to remove noise. But you should do that, you should apply low, high, low-high or other filters to data.

If you getting symetric analog data and apply filter to data, they should be same.

Comment: I see! In that case, how can I make sure that my soundwave that I produce by IFFT will be periodic? Its intention is that after converting the data from the frequency to the sound wave, the sound wave carries the data from the transmitting device to the receiving device. If the sound wave is periodic, then the receiving device is able to convert the information from the sound wave back to the frequency domain and extract the data encoded there. If the sound wave is periodic, then it does not matter where the soundwave recorded from, the receiving device can still decode the same frequencies.

Comment: I think there are two ways to do this. 
1-) You should make sure that the data you produce is periodic. 
2-) After applying the FFT to the data, you should observe that the numbers from the Frequency/Amplitude traffic are equal. If not, you should apply low,high pass filters to remove contradictory data. So, you can get clean(frequently) data.

You can check the follow link:
https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/#filtering-the-signal

Comment: Apologies, I think I may not have been too clear in the explanation of the issue. I'm trying to get a sound wave from the data, but I need to ensure that my sound wave is periodic. How do I tweak my data to ensure that?